# Datetime formatting in python

Tags: python, string, datetime, formatting

Should be simple enough. I have a datetime object in python, I need it to be of the form

```
20131002
```

Is there a way to format this without having to resort to breaking the date into it's components and putting them together in a string manually?

Comment: Have you looked at `datetime.strftime`?

Comment: thanks. That was easy. 

Would you reccomend deleting this question? The question DID get answered, but now it almost seems trivial.

Comment: I've posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is super easy in the Python `datetime` library:

```
from datetime import datetime

test = datetime.now()     # This is just some test datetime object
test.strftime('%Y%m%d')  # This is the format statement
```

However, a quick Google search shows me that you would find similar answers by searching for "python datetime format".

Answer (score 1):

Use `datetime.strftime`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.now()
>>> dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
'20131003'
```